# Python translate def into lambda?

Tags: python, function, lambda

How can I translate def functions into lambda python?

```
def a(x):
if x % 7 == 0:
    x += x // 7
    return x
else:
    return x
```

i tried like this but it didnt work

```
a= lambda x: x += x//7 if x%7 else x
```

and how can I translate this too. I don't understand this one

```
def b(x):
if x == True:
    r = 32
elif x == False:
    r = 38
```

Comment: a=lambda x : x + (x//7) if x%7==0 else x

Comment: The lambda equivalent of your `b` function is just `lambda x: None`... It doesn't do anything, it assigns to a local variable then returns None.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot do assignment inside a lambda

```
a= lambda x: x + (x//7 if x%7 else x)

x = a(15)
```

as pointed out in the comments I think your lambda would actually be

```
a= lambda x: (x + x//7) if x % 7==0 else x
```